# Divide document into a black and color file before printing

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, print-to-pdf

I want to print a large docx file that has many pages of color images but I need to print these pages only as color and the remaining as b/w to save money.

Is there a way to detect and create a new color pdf file for the figure pages only. and save the remaining pages into a new B/W pdf file.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If the B/W pages are plain black text, then your printer will automatically print those with black ink/toner only. The colour pages will of course be printed in colour. The only problem occurs when your document contains greyscale images. In that case the printer **may** (depending on printer and settings) use some colour inks to get a larger grey gamut. In that case, see if there is a driver setting to print greys with black ink only.

Hence, in the majority of cases, you don't have to worry about it. If there are greyscale images and there is no suitable driver setting, the amount of colour ink used will be minimal, so again it will not increase the cost by much.